# Parsing text files and generating a CSV

Tags: ruby, linux, perl, parsing, csv

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about parsing a group of files containing raw log data (results of crontab -l) and convert this data into a CSV file. The entries in the files are like so:

```
10,25,40,55 * * * * /some/cron/here > /dev/null 2>&1
30 */4 * * * /some/cron/here
```

And so on.

I want to get them into this format in a CSV file:

```
Cronjob | # of Servers | Every minute | Every hour | Every day | Every week | Every month
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CronHere| 10 | N | N | Y | Y | Y
CronHere| 8 | Y | N | N | Y | Y
```

And so on.

Can anyone give me some examples of how I might go about doing this?

Comment: Note that your question contains a contradiction in terms. A CSV file contains Comma Separated Values (CSV). Your values have a different separator.

Comment: @MetaEd: The inputs are `crontab -l` listings, the desired output is a CSV file with the specified format, no contradictions here.

Comment: @muistooshort: He's saying that the output file shouldn't be called CSV because it's using pipes instead of commas as delimiters. Pedantic, yes, even if most people would see that a CSV with a different delimiter is parsed and written exactly the same as a CSV with comma delimiters.

Comment: @CanSpice: I took the "pipe table" as a description of the format but I could be wrong (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: Sorry if there's any confusion. I basically just need to parse the data to get it into the format stated in my original post so that I can import it into a spreadsheet. I'm attempting to figure out how to do this in ruby, but haven't had much luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up accomplishing this task, thanks to ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

crons = []
counts = []
cparts = []
basedir = "/logdirectory"
def YorN(part)
  if part == "*"
    "N"
  else
    "Y"
  end
end
Dir.new(basedir).entries.each do |logfile|
  unless File.directory? logfile
    if logfile.split('.')[1] == 'log'
      file = File.new(logfile, "r")
      while (line = file.gets)
        parts = line.split(' ')
        if parts[5,parts.length-5]
          cmd = parts[5,parts.length-5].join(' ')
          idx = crons.index(cmd)
          if idx
             counts[idx] += 1
          else
            crons << cmd
            idx = crons.index(cmd)
            counts[idx] = 1
            cparts[idx] = parts[0,5] # an Array containing another Array !
          end
        else
          puts "Error on: #{line} in file #{logfile}"
        end
      end
      file.close
    end
  end
end
# OUTPUT results
puts "# Servers  Min  Hour  DOM  Month DOW  Cronjob"
crons.each do |c|
  idx = crons.index(c)
  puts "#{counts[idx]} #{YorN(cparts[idx][0])} #{YorN(cparts[idx][1])} #{YorN(cparts[idx][2])} #{YorN(cparts[idx][3])} #{YorN(cparts[idx][4])} #{crons[idx]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse those files with Perl regexps, arrange data and save output using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split q( ), $_, 6;
    print join q(|), $line[5], @line[0..4], "\n";
}
```

As for enumerating the number of servers for which a task occurs, you need to better define how you differentiate tasks --- by name only, or by fully matching all arguments.  Once you do that, you could use a hash for counting.